# Some applications on my unbuntu won't launch (document viewer)

Tags: libraries, desktop

My Document viewer is not able to launch. When I open it using commandline it gives me the following error:

```
evince
evince: error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.6: failed to map     segment from shared object: Permission denied
```

when I sudo it gives me the following error:

```
sudo evince ass3.pdf 
No protocol specified

** (evince:13785): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

How to make it open normally, by normally I mean when I click on a pdf with my mouse?